# MongoDB how to find all elements in an array exist a field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I came across a query that I couldn't make. The use case I was told is that I would need to find if there is any faulty data where a book doesn't contain a title. Books happen to be a array. So I need to find out if all books in the `books` array must contain a `title` field.

I have only came up with the query for the first element like so
`{"books": {$exists: true, $not: {$size: 0}}, "books.0.title": {$exists: false}}`. How do I do it for all elements?

Document:

```
{
  id: oid(abc123..)
  name: John Doe
  books: [
    {
      title: MyBook1
    }
    {
      title: MyBook2
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: can you post your sample data set?

Comment: Do you need to return only those values of the array where the given field exists?

Comment: I am just trying to query if such document exists (book in books without title)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use dot notation for querying mongodb, so you can try something like this

```
Books.find({ 'books.title': {$ne: null}})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/#aggregation-pipeline) for this..

You can check out [an example query here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IGd2dx6N5HA) showing you how this works.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$books" },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        { "books.title": { $exists: true, $eq: "" }},
        { "books.title": { $exists: true, $eq: null }}
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query

```
db.getCollection("books").find({
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      { $size: "$books" },
      {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$books",
            cond: { $ne: ["$$this.title", undefined] }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

or

```
db.getCollection("books").find({
  $expr: {
    $allElementsTrue: {
      $map: { input: "$books", in: { $ne: ["$$this.title", undefined] } }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$books" },
  {
    $match: {
        "books.title": { $exists: true},
    }
  }
])
```